# Multiple constructor selection using unity

Tags: c#, parameters, constructor, unity-container

Having looked I have not seen a answer that specifically addresses my question. I understand that unity takes the multi-parameter ctor first. However when the parameters are of the same type or differing types this leads me to some weird misunderstanding. Having:

```
public MyClass(string s1, string s2)

public MyClass(string s1)

public MyClass(Guid g1)
```

why when I supply a `ResolverOverride` with a `ParameterOverride` of `Guid` does Unity try the double string parameter first?

When I supply a similar situation with a single string in the ParameterOverride does it still try the double string parameter first - have I not told Unity explicitly that?

Finally, how do I stop Unity from doing this? Must I setup the `Resolve` or `RegisterType` using some "magic"?

Please can someone clear up the dissonance happening in my skull....?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it selects constructor with InjectionConstructor attribute. Then constructor with most parameters count.

[Here](https://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/a-schematic-view-of-dependency-injection-in-unity-ioc/) is good article about it.